# jQuery - resizing form input based on value's width?

Tags: jquery, forms, input, resize

Is it possible to get input's value width and resize the input dynamically so the value will fit?

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/bzBdX/2/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the jQuery code :

```
$('input').each(function(){
var value = $(this).val();
var size  = value.length;
// playing with the size attribute
//$(this).attr('size',size);

// playing css width
size = size*2; // average width of a char
$(this).css('width',size*3);

})​;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bzBdX/7/

Comment: This is not working on jsfiddle, please consider adding 'keydown' function to listen to keypresses

Answer (score 11):

I have a jQuery plugin on GitHub: https://github.com/MartinF/jQuery.Autosize.Input

It mirrors the value of the input so it can calculate the actual length instead of guessing or other approaches mentioned.

You can see an live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jw9oqz0e/

Example:

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Autosize" data-autosize-input='{ "space": 40 }' />

input[type="data-autosize-input"] {
  width: 90px;
  min-width: 90px;
  max-width: 300px;
  transition: width 0.25s;    
}
```

You just use css to set min/max-width and use a transition on the width if you want a nice effect.

You can specify the space / distance to the end as the value in json notation for the data-autosize-input attribute on the input element.

Of course you can also just initialize it using jQuery

```
$("selector").autosizeInput();
```

Answer (score 8):

Current answers were waay to complicated. Heres a quick one

```
$('#myinput').width($('#myinput').prop('scrollWidth'))
```

Adding the above to input keydown/up/press events is trivial.
Tested in chrome

Comment: Technically the question mentioned jquery. However this is the best solution to the problem. Rgds

Comment: This doesn't seem to decrease the width when I delete characters though.

Answer (score 1):

Something simple :

```
$('#resizeme').keydown(function(){  // listen for keypresses
 var contents = $(this).val();      // get value
 var charlength = contents.length;  // get number of chars
 newwidth =  charlength*9;          // rough guesstimate of width of char
 $(this).css({width:newwidth});     // apply new width
});​
```

You could change the multiplier on personal preference / text-size

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/bzBdX/6/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
        width: $(this).val().length*7
    },100)                
    })
})​
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/bzBdX/11/

So i made an example where it tries to calculate the width by
inserting letters in a span and calculating there width

```
(function() {
    var mDiv = $("<span />").text("M").appendTo("body"),
        mSize = mDiv.width();
    mDiv.detach();

    var letterSize = function(s) {
        var sDiv = $("<span />").text("M" + s + "M").appendTo("body"),
            sSize = sDiv.width();

        sDiv.detach();

        return (sSize - (mSize * 2)) * 0.89;
    };

    $("input[data-resise-me]").each(function() {
        var minSize = $(this).width();

        var resizeInput = function() {
            var calcSize = $.map($(this).val(), letterSize);
            var inputSize = 0;
            $.each(calcSize, function(i, v) { inputSize += v; });

            $(this).width( inputSize < minSize ? minSize : inputSize );
        };

        $(this).on({ keydown: resizeInput, keyup: resizeInput });
    });
} ());
```

Theres probably a much better way of doing this.

Comment: Why do you multiply by 0.89?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @ManseUK. This line worked for me.
JQuery version 1.8

> $('#resizeme').css({width:newwidth});

Answer (score 1):

All those solutions based on number of characters are quite weak, because each character could be of a different width if it is not a monotype font. I'm solving this problem with creating a div containing value of text input with the same font properties and getting its width as a required one.

Something like this:

```
function resizeInput() {
    $('body').append('<div class="new_width">'+$(this).val()+'</div>');
    $(this).css('width', $('.new_width').width());
    $('.new_width').remove()
}
$('input')
    // event handler
    .keyup(resizeInput)
    // resize on page load
   .each(resizeInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

this example as been tested on Chrome 25 and Firefox 19. (http://jsfiddle.net/9ezyz/)

```
function input_update_size()
{
    var value = $(this).val();
    var size  = 12;

    // Looking for font-size into the input
    if (this.currentStyle)
        size = this.currentStyle['font-size'];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        size =  document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this,null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
    $(this).stop().animate({width:(parseInt(size)/2+1)*value.length},500);
    //$(this).width((parseInt(size)/2+1)*value.length);
}

$('input')
    .each(input_update_size)
    .keyup(input_update_size);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check this demo on js fiddle ... http://jsfiddle.net/ninadajnikar/bzBdX/9/ .

You update the width values as you like it