# How can I trim an input element's width to the size of the initial text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I set the initial width of an `input` element to be large enough to just surround the initial text? Example of what I want to achieve: [Silverlight app example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBJ80.png).

I've tried setting the `width` property but it doesn't give me what I want:

```
<input type="text" style ="width: auto;" value="Default value"></input>
<input type="text" style ="width: 2%;" value ="Longer default value"></input>
<input type="text" style ="width: 100%;"value="Default value"></input>
```

I either get excess white space or the text is truncated.

Is this possible?

I'm targeting HTML5 browsers only (IE9+, Chrome, FF), so CSS3 solutions would be fine. Javascript solutions welcomed too.

Thanks

Comment: if this helps [Resizing input based on value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328682/jquery-resizing-form-input-based-on-values-width) [**Demo from David Laberge**](http://jsfiddle.net/bzBdX/338/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to use jQuery to set the widths:

```
$.each($('input'), function(){
    $(this).css('width',(($(this).val().length) * 6 + 'px'));
});
```

Multiply by 6 seemed to be the best with default font. You might need to adjust it if you have used custom fonts for inputs.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2479t/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="Default value" value="Default value"></input>
<input type="text"  placeholder ="Longer default value" value="Longer default value"></input>
<input type="text"  placeholder="Default value" value="Default value"></input>
```

Comment: What if he/she sets width from css larger than placeholer??

Comment: if css is set then it will take the width defined in css, otherwise by default it will set to placeholder text..

Comment: No, that doesn't help: it just makes them all the same width. It just makes them all the same length. In my sample HTML was trying to show that I'd tried different things.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/4Qsa8/3/)**

html

```
<div class="resizing-input">
    First: <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder" value="Default value"/>
    <span  style="display:none"></span>
</div><br>
<div class="resizing-input">
    Second: <input type="text" value ="Longer default value"/>
    <span  style="display:none"></span>
</div><br>
<div class="resizing-input">
    Third: <input type="text" value ="Longer default value longer still longer"/>
    <span  style="display:none"></span>
</div><br>
<div class="resizing-input">
    First: <input type="text" placeholder="with placeholder as well"/>
    <span  style="display:none"></span>
</div><br>
```

css

```
.resizing-input input, .resizing-input span {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $inputs = $('.resizing-input');

    // Resize based on text if text.length > 0
    // Otherwise resize based on the placeholder
    function resizeForText(text) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!text.trim()) {
            text = $this.attr('placeholder').trim();
        }
        var $span = $this.parent().find('span');
        $span.text(text);
        var $inputSize = $span.width();
        $this.css("width", $inputSize);
    }

    $inputs.find('input').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which && e.charCode) {
            var c = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode | e.charCode);
            var $this = $(this);
            resizeForText.call($this, $this.val() + c);
        }
    });

    // Backspace event only fires for keyup
    $inputs.find('input').keyup(function (e) { 
        if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
            resizeForText.call($(this), $(this).val());
        }
    });

    $inputs.find('input').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        resizeForText.call($this, $this.val())
    });
});
```

source : [Adjust width of input field to its input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392493/adjust-width-of-input-field-to-its-input)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var input = document.getElementById ("myInput");           
input.style.width = (input.value.length * 7) + "px";
```

You can change 7 to 6 0r 8 according to yout text size

and for setting it dynamically on keyPress

```
<input id="txt" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';">
```

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2DLZB/)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mJMpw/617/): this might help you

html:

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Autosize" data-autosize-input='{ "space": 40 }' />
```

css:

```
input {
width: auto;
min-width: 0px;
max-width: 300px;
transition: width 0.25s; }
```

JS:

```
check the fiddle for the js code
```

Comment: But here you are adding external js library