# Scroll Width always returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing a bit of program in which whenever it detects an input change in the **textbox** it needs to do something. But it doesn't work for me. So i Change i started giving the value in console to verify it whenever it detects a change in input it always returns **undefined**.
 How can i get the size of the text a user has entered in pixels?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    input[type=text] {
        height: 20px;
        width: 100px;
    }
</style>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="func"></input>
</body>
<script>
    $("#func").change(function () {
      console.log($("func").scrollWidth);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: As other said scrollWidth has not wrapper in jQuery, So you can get it with $(selector).prop('scrollWidth').

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two bugs in your code. First, you select the element `func` without a hash. If you select an id in jQuery, you are required to use a `#` in front of the id name (see [reference](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector)). So, you need to select it like this: `$('#func')`.

Second, you need the DOM element of `$('#func')` and not its jQuery wrapper to access the property `scrollWidth`. You can do that by using `$('#func')[0].scrollWidth` or `$('#func').get().scrollWidth`.

I would however recommend you to use the [jQuery `width` function](http://api.jquery.com/width) to get the width of the input field: `$('#func').width()`.

Comment: I need to get the size of the pixels of the input no the whole inputbox size?

Comment: There is no such function available to get the width of the input field content. There are however some approches here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392493/adjust-width-of-input-field-to-its-input and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328682/jquery-resizing-form-input-based-on-values-width

Comment: I know this is somewhat old, but `$('#func').get().scrollWidth` will return "undefined" if you don't specify the index, so when getting the first element, using index 0, it should be `$('#func').get(0).scrollWidth`

Answer (score 2):

scrollWidth is a DOM-Element attribute, not a jQuery attribute, `$('#func').get().scrollWidth` should be defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
const element = $("#func");

// Get the scroll width using the DOM element
const scrollWidth = element[0].scrollWidth;

console.log(scrollWidth);
```