# Style form, underline input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have [this form](http://codepen.io/masadeus/pen/oLOZko) and I want the placeholder and the input to be underlined. The underline should have the width of the input, as one types the underline grows. With Firefox is an easy thing, just applying:

`input {
    text-decoration: underline;
}`

even though I am not sure if there is a way to style the line. Anyways, when it comes to Chrome, well, not that easy anymore!

I have tried some solutions with jQuery from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328682/jquery-resizing-form-input-based-on-values-width), but they don't work that good (they would only work proper with a monospaced typography). You can check one of these solutions outcommenting the JS in the codepen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Problem is placholder not underlined in Chrome? Cause text is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with two different solutions.

The **first solution** uses jQuery to dynamically resize the input to match that of an hidden `<span>` element. That way, it you don't have to guess the "average size" of a character or anything like that.

```
$("body").keydown(function(e){
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(e.which == 32){
        $("#clone").append("&nbsp;");
    }
      $("#clone").text($('input').val());
    $('input').width($("#clone").width() + 40);
  }, 100);
});
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/pz0f5bam/

---

The **second solution** is more just CSS. I started by setting the input width to 100% so that you don't have to worry about it's width being too small. Then if you add `text-decoration: underline;` to the input it looks like it is growing.

I also added styling to the placeholder to make it look like it has a minimum size.

```
input{
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/vrodL180/

Comment: I used the first one at it allows me style the underline. Neat trick!!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

edit :

```
 input:not([type=submit]):not([type=file]) {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

for complete solution and largest support use

```
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-decoration: underline;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-decoration: underline; 
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/happymacarts/pen/WxWXdK)

Comment: But this would still leave me with the problem of styling the input, which actually is the main problem.

Comment: check my post again?

Comment: what additional do you want to do with the input?  did you try   text-decoration: underline; on the input element?

Comment: i suggested an edit to the answer and added the codepen http://codepen.io/happymacarts/pen/WxWXdK

Comment: Thanks! But I still went for @spencerlarry 's solutions because it still allows me to style the underline.

Answer (score 2):

To style the Chrome placeholder use:

```
input,
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: But this would still leave me with the problem of styling the input, which actually is the main problem.

Comment: What problems man? Just use same style for `input` and `input::-webkit-input-placeholder`. You said you wanted to look as in Firefox, here is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I added a couple of lines to @spencerlarry 's solution so that when the user erases the input the width goes back to the original one. Just leave it here in case someone finds it useful ;)

```
$("body").keydown(function(e){
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(e.which == 32){
        $("#clone").append("&nbsp;");
      }
      $("#clone").text($('input').val());
      $('input').width($("#clone").width());
      // if user erases email go back to original width
      if($("#clone").width() == 0) {
        $('input').width(310);
      }
    }, 100);
  });
```

Comment: Oh and I also found this: https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-grow-input/demo.html