# Set input width to fit text size

Tags: css

I have and input with icon, looking like this:
[image: screenshot]

```
<div class="input-with-icon">
  <input type="text" value="abcdefeghijklmnopqrtvuvwxyz" class="form-control">
  <span class="icon icon-calendar"></span>
</div>
```

[live demo](https://bootstrap-themes.github.io/dashboard/docs/index.html#icon-input)

Is it possible to adjust CSS so the input will always fit the text width? e.g. it will stretch as I type.

currently, `.input-with-icon` has fixed width, but if I set it to auto, input won't stretch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make html text input field grow as I type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168727/make-html-text-input-field-grow-as-i-type)

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using JavaScript. The reason is that when you are entering text into `<input>` or `<textarea>` elements, you simply change their `value`. You make no DOM manipulations to the elements which will affect their widths.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="txt" type="text" value="Hello World!" />
input {
min-width:50px!important;
max-width:99.99%!important;
transition: width 0.25s;
text-align:center;
}
function resizable (el, factor) {
var int = Number(factor) || 7.7;
function resize() {el.style.width = ((el.value.length+1) * int) + 'px'}
var e = 'keyup,keypress,focus,blur,change'.split(',');
for (var i in e) el.addEventListener(e[i],resize,false);
resize();
}
resizable(document.getElementById('txt'),7);
```

Answer (score -2):

You have many option for that. The **First** option is to change your `<input type="text">` into `<textarea class="form-control"></textarea>`. `<textarea>` can handle much better characters than `<input type="text">`.
The **Second** option is use [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/bzBdX/11/). This example is from @megakorre in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328682/jquery-resizing-form-input-based-on-values-width). Dont forget to Vote up or put a check if you got the answer. That's all dude! Happy Coding! :)

Comment: I changed input to textarea, set rows to 1, set white-space to nowrap and still not working. I got scrollbars. Javascript solution is not acceptable

Answer (score -3):

```
<div class="input-with-icon">
<input type="text" value="tes" class="form-control">
</div>
input[type="data-autosize-input"] {
 width: 90px;
min-width: 90px;
 max-width: 300px;
 transition: width 0.25s;    
 }
```

Comment: This requires a jQuery plugin. Not sure this applies to this question (as he asked for CSS solution).

Comment: i have already gave you css code so you can apply given code in any of them.

Comment: Code does not require JQuery  plugin , So you can directly use the above code .

Comment: How does it work exactly? Here's a copy-paste of the above code into jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ynrfn9wr/

Comment: First of all create an HTML page and include your HTML code .

Comment: First of all create an HTML page and include your HTML code

Comment: Show me on the fiddle above, how you make your code work. I have copied your code completely. Edit the fiddle as needed and share the edits here (preferably in your answer itself).

Comment: can you share me code have you create .so i can give you exactly answer.

Comment: If you have working solution, just share it. but the easiest and most convenient way would be modify and share this: https://jsfiddle.net/ynrfn9wr/